# Conditional Form on Popup Squarespace

Tags: javascript, forms, squarespace

I have a squarespace site (page here https://www.americangardenhouse.com/products/o-sweet-viola) I'm trying to create an a conditional form (in this case it would be on the additional product form). After selecting the product variants and then clicking "Add to Cart" the popup product form displays with two radio inputs. If "Yes" is selected, I want the additional product form fields to display (currently hidden CSS) and if "No" then an html message to appear prompting the customer to click the product form "Add to Cart" button.

```
<style>
#textarea-yui_3_17_2_1_1585523845981_190824,
#address-yui_3_17_2_1_1585523845981_456969,
#email-yui_3_17_2_1_1585523845981_459960,
#phone-yui_3_17_2_1_1585523845981_461162 {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1585593158170_218442 input:radio').click(function() {
    selection = $(this).val();
    if (selection == 'Yes') {
      $('.form-item').show;
    }
  else
    if (selection == 'No') {
      $('form').html('Maybe Next Time. Please complete adding this product to your card by clicking "Add to Cart"');
    }
});
</script>
```

The CSS is loaded using code injector into the page header and the script is in the footer. AJAX is currently disabled.

Problem is, the click event is not working on the popup. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a simple JS issue that you can fix.

Your click event isn't working because it's not delegated. The popup that holds these buttons (sqs-modal-lightbox) is added via AJAX on the page.

You need to do something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1585593158170_218442 input:radio', function() {
    selection = $(this).val();
    if (selection == 'Yes') {
      $('.form-item').show;
    }
  else
    if (selection == 'No') {
      $('form').html('Maybe Next Time. Please complete adding this product to your card by clicking "Add to Cart"');
    }
});
```

Note that a more proper way to check the value is to use the change event and grab the input.prop()

Resources:

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName

You can also try something like this (haven't tested it):

```js
$(document).on('change', '#radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1585593158170_218442 input:radio', function() {
 const inputValue = $(this).val();

 return inputValue == 'Yes' ?
  $('.form-item').show() :
  $('form').html('Maybe Next Time. Please complete adding this product to your card by clicking "Add to Cart"');
});
```